# Can a gene transfer from a plasmid to a bacterial chromosome?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, genomics

Plasmids are involved in providing resistance to antibiotics. So, can that gene or any other gene transfer from the plasmid to the bacterial chromosome?
Is there any chance where antibiotic resistance is conferred by chromosomal DNA (not plasmid DNA)?

Answer (score 3):

Briefly: yes.

It has been known for some decades that plasmids (including those that encode antibiotic resistance) [can recombine with the host genome](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3489710/).

Indeed, the selective pressure to perform such transfers makes it possibly more interesting to infer why it *doesn't* happen (in appropriate contexts), for example in [this paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2020.0467).